# Office 365 - Online Templates greyed out and unavailable

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-365, windows-server-2019, microsoft-office

Environment: Microsoft Office 16 (Office 365) running on Windows Server 2019 with RDS.

In Microsoft Office 16, all users are unable to search for any online templates in the new documents pane.

[Search for online templates greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKfRv.png)

- I have checked the privacy settings in the office applications themselves.
  [Privacy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8qRu.png)
- I have tried disabling "Automatically detect settings" in IE LAN settings, did not make any difference.
- I have verified that there is no firewall blocking access to office.com or office.net
- I have checked all GPOs for anything related to Internet and Office with no results.
  [Active GPOs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEtXu.png)
- I have checked the registry for "*disablehyperlinkstowebtemplates*" in *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\General* and didn't find it at all.

I feel like I have tried and checked everything, and I'm certain it is just a flip somewhere that needs to be switched.

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a related group policy setting "**Allow the use of connected experiences in Office that download online content**", I suggest you enable it to check whether you can force this Office feature on.

The path in Group Policy is `User Configuration > Microsoft Office 2016 > Privacy > Trusted Center`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZGa5.png)

Comment: Better late than never, but thank you very much, your solution worked :)